# Laptop Power not going through

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a HP dv5-1000US.

Just now I faced a peculiar situation.

Normally when I plug the power adapter cord, the LED at the power input socket (on the side) stays completely on and so does the power LED in front. Today I saw the side LED going on and off. I also noticed that the battery was not charging. So the laptop was running on battery alone.

I then removed the battery. When I connected the power cord, the side LED was then completely lit, but the laptop didnt start (it normally does if directly connected even with no battery).

Now my battery has completely drained out and my laptop is dead.

Apparently the power from the adapter is not charging the battery, nor is it supplying power to the laptop independantly, though the laptop recognises the power input. What could be the problem ?

Would replacing the adapter help ? (Dont want to buy an adapter if this is not the solution)

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

2 main potential sources of the problem: the AC adapter or the DC jack (power socket).

Do you have a multimeter that you could test the AC adapter with? Check the voltage marked on the AC adapter and see if that is what is being output. If you move the cable around while it's connected to the laptop, does the light appear?

It's also possible that the DC jack has (a) become dislodged from it's holster internally or (b) if it's soldered to the board, it's legs have broken or the centre pin has been damaged. If (a) then hot glue will hold it in place moving forward or if (b) you'll need a new DC jack and a soldering iron.

Comment: The power seems to go into the laptop quite fine as the LED glows when connected with battery / or blinks when battery removed. No broken legs or otherwise. The laptop works fine with battery, but not with direct power - though the LED shows recognition of power input

Comment: Have you managed to do a test with the multimeter to check voltages?

Comment: Took laptop & ac adapter to local Staples to check out (the laptop was completely kept in cold storage last 2 days). The tech support guy tried it with his adapter & it worked fine. Then he plugged my adapter - & IT WORKED FINE ?? The tech guy felt that the system could have been "boosted" by his adapter. Just cannot make out what went wrong - and more importantly why it became right ?? The system is now working fine at my home too. I'll have to wait at least a week or 10 days to be sure that all's well. Perhaps there is a weak chip inside which goes off and on after a couple of days cooling.